# videojs video initial loading time

Tags: javascript, video.js

Currently using videojs and facing some issues with initial video load time. I am using `preset:auto` to load the video. But my video starts after 3,4mb of buffering(downloading data) that take around 20,30 secs to initially starts the video.

Is there any way that video could start instantly ?

Comment: You're saying that playback starts after 3 or 4 MB gets downloaded, but your title refers to loading-TIME question. You haven't mentioned how much TIME it is taking for the initial download?  How many seconds does it take, before playback starts???

Comment: it takes about 20,30 secs depending on internet speed.